# Spring Data JPA projection with ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String userName;
    // Getters/setters
}

@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    private String comment;
    // Getters/setters
}
```

I want to generate a JPQL query in a Spring Data JPA repository which gives me the authors with all their comments. My projection is

```
public interface AuthorProjection {
    String getUserName();
    List<String> getComments();
}
```

and my JPQL query is

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {

    @Query(value= "SELECT a.id as id, \n" +
            "    a.userName as userName,\n" +
            "    c.comment as comments\n" +
            "from Author a \n" +
            "left join Comment c on c.author = a")
    List<AuthorProjection> authorsWithComments();
}

public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> { 
}
```

This generates the following raw SQL query via Hibernate (Underlying DB is PostgreSQL):

```
select author0_.id as col_0_0_, author0_.user_name as col_1_0_,comment1_.comment as col_2_0_ from author author0_ left outer join comment comment1_ on (comment1_.author_id=author0_.id)
```

My test data consists of one Author with two Comments. Unfortunately, when I run this, I always get two authors (which is actually the same Author) with one comment each. This is of course how the DB returns each row (the raw SQL looks nice and how it should be). Is it possible for either Hibernate or Spring Data JPA (or whichever is responsible) to merge all comments into the list, or do I need to write Java code which merges the rows based on the author id?

If possible, I would like to have the DB perform all the data transformation already and have a nicely structured Projection as output from the query.

My test for demonstration is:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
class JpatestApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository commentRepository;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        var author = new Author();
        author.setUserName("John Doe");
        var savedAuthor = authorRepository.save(author);

        var comment1 = new Comment();
        comment1.setComment("First comment").setAuthor(savedAuthor);
        commentRepository.save(comment1);

        var comment2 = new Comment();
        comment2.setComment("Second comment").setAuthor(savedAuthor);
        commentRepository.save(comment2);

        authorRepository.authorsWithComments().forEach(
                projection -> System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", projection.getUserName(), projection.getComments())
        );
    }
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
John Doe, [First comment]
John Doe, [Second comment]
```

And run directly in PostgreSQL, it gives:

```
 col_0_0_ | col_1_0_ |    col_2_0_
----------+----------+----------------
        1 | John Doe | First comment
        1 | John Doe | Second comment
(2 rows)
```

My expected Java output is:

```
John Doe, [First comment, Second comment]
```

Is this even possible with JPA?

Comment: Can you add you raw sql query ?

Comment: I've updated it with a simple working example.

Answer (score 2):

Use relation in `Author` entity to fetch comments of author.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then query this way

```
@Query(value= "SELECT a.userName as userName, a.comments as comments from Author a")
List<AuthorProjection> authorsWithComments();
```

And projection like

```
public interface AuthorProjection {
    String getUserName();
    List<Comment> getComments();
}
```

Comment: Is this also possible without altering the entities? My actual query is much more complex like this, and I don't want to alter the entities. But I want to let the database do as much as work as possible.

Comment: If you don't use relation then how JPA integrates all comments for the author. Your query return the cartesian product after joining that's why you get one comments only. Or you have to manually integrates all comments for author.

Comment: Did you try this solution ?

Comment: I could not because there is no OneToMany relation and I could not convince my co-worker to let me add it :-(. In the end I created a transactional @Service method where I called multiple repositories and just aggregated the result in Java. I did want to try it completely in JPQL, but in the end I just needed the result.

Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Is this supposed to work? For me, it still results in two AuthorProjection objects, each with only a single comment entry in the list. I use a H2 database, could this be an issue?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My domain model has a OneToMany from Author to list of Comments, but not vice versa, could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You get all the comments by just query the authors. You need to add extra List in Author class.

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you can use JAP Reposity

```java
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository  extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {

}
```

`CrudRepository` already implement many useful API, such as `findAll()`, `findById()`, you don't need to write any sqls.